# Wireless authentication pop-up greyed out

Tags: wireless, networking

### The Problem

Frequently I get online without being asked to input a password, and then, after several minutes of having a connection, the connection stops and I am prompted for a password for the network. However, the username field and the connect button are greyed out, like in the picture.

[image: Greyed out authentication screen.]

This is... thoroughly irritating, to say the least. How can I fix it? (Google and the search bar have failed me so far.)

### Details

- If I close the pop-up, it will reappear in a couple minutes.
- Occasionally rebooting the computer will allow me to get back on the network.
- I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.
- The networks seem fine; my old mac laptop has no troubles connecting to the same networks in the same locations.
- This doesn't happen consistently.

Comment: Is there any more information I can give to help figure this out?

Comment: What is the model of your wireless router? Can you show all the the configuration that you can? You can upload the output in paste.ubuntu.com and then link it here.

Comment: @Lucio Unfortunately I don't know anything about the configuration of the router since it is my school's network. I can try and ask someone who works on it though. How might the router impact the fact that the message fields are ghosted out?

Comment: Yes, tell to the network administrator about your situation and he should know where is the problem.

Comment: @Lucio Why would it have to do with the network though if my mac and other peoples' windows computers connect without any problems?

Comment: Actually, I don't know. But the administrator of the network should have a degree and I'm pretty sure that *he* knows more than *me* by now :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can look into are the certificates and authentication you're using. I checked Eduroam info of [your university](https://wiki.carleton.edu/display/itskb/Eduroam+Wireless+Setup) and it has info on Linux but it wants you to go through XpressConnect. It was like that at my old uni, too, but only for Windows and Mac (I believe) You can try [this guide](https://footprints.york.ac.uk/MRcgi/MRTicketPage.pl?USER=&MRP=0&MAJOR_MODE=DETAILS&MAXMININC=&MRNUMBERLIST=&LASTID=3232&ABN=&GRPDETAIL=&HISTORYKEY=&CUSTM=&MR=32194&PROJECTID=1) (steps 4 and 5 in particular) which lists out the steps for Linux. I think Eduroam is supposed to be worldwide so I would assume settings are the same everywhere.

EDIT: My current university's [guide](http://www.icts.uct.ac.za/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=3196#Set_connect_Linux_%28Ubuntu%29) doesn't have the same steps as the other so perhaps they are not universal settings. Still worth a try though I think.

If all else fails, you could disable and re-enable networking or wireless instead of rebooting your computer. It's not going to fix anything but it's somewhat faster (if it even works).

Comment: Thanks for the advice- I'll try the guide out. (I'm actually at Carleton College.) Interestingly, disabling/re-enabling wireless has never got me back online, even though rebooting the computer does.

Comment: sorry! i saw the email address and took the first hit on google... rookie mistake. i've updated the link and answer to make up for it.
let me know how it works out!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the saved connection?
Click the network icon in the top right, click "edit connections", go to the wireless tab, click your connection in the list on the left and click delete.

Then disable/enable networking.  That should clear any saved authentication info and allow you to put in a new username.

I'd compare the security settings with those on a machine that connects normally as well.

Comment: Thanks, but everything seems to be in order there.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I'm on my local network at home. Sometimes the connection is just lost and then it asks for the password. I also experienced that if I leave the laptop for a couple hours and this happens then the windows start popping up continuously, even though I didn't press cancel or anything because I wasn't even close to the computer.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! It looks like the information in your response regarding the situations in which you experience the issue would be better left as a comment to the original question; see http://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion for details.